# Unable to load dsr files in vb6 project

Tags: vb6

I am currently trying to open up an old project that I have in my possession. Its written in vb6 and I have attempted to upgrade to a newer version but I get a slew of errors saying I need to have a working vb6 environment with all references in order to upgrade.

I have vb6 itself working and when I open my project file any .dsr, .dsx files will not load with the following error (which prompts me to go to the log file).

> Line 2: Class {BD4B4E61-F7B8-11D0-964D-00A0C9273C2A} of control crBooking was not a loaded control class.
>   Line 0: The file C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\VB6 - Conversion\VBSource\crBooking2.Dsr could not be loaded.

All form files along with class modules and the project file itself load just fine. I have no idea what this means or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the error logs? Sometimes you will have *.log files in the same directory as the source files. Sounds like you have a bad\invalid reference somewhere.

Comment: From memory alone: are these something to do with Crystal Reports? Do you have Crystal Reports installed on your PC?

Comment: @MarkJ: I think DSR's are actually created by using VB6's built-in Data Reporting tools (I don't remember what this feature is actually called in the IDE, I'm also doing this from memory). I only know that because we had an old project where someone was using the IDE's built-in report designer for something, and it's the only project we have that has `.dsr` files in source control.

Answer (score 1):

The `.dsr` files are generated by any so called Designer. Those are extensions which can be added to the VB6 environment.
On example is the Designer which is used by the `Visual Basic for Applications IDE` extension. This one is used, if you are developing an extension for VB6 or VBA itself.

As already mentioned, the GUID seems to belong to a Crystal Reports component. So it might be necessary to either install a greater version of VB6 (some of them come with a Crystal Reports light) or to install the Crystal Reports software itself.